# Configmap environment variables of one pod are visible from other pods of the cluster

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

We have a collection of services deployed on a GKE cluster. All is fine and runs like a charm for years now, but we have noticed that all the environment variables created from configmaps or secrets are visible from all the pods running on the same node, regardless if these env vars have been defined in the related deployment YAML or not.

It is quite simple to reproduce :

- create deployments for several different service (using different images of course)
- create distinct configmaps and secrets for each of them
- define environments for each deployment, referencing its own configmap and secrets
- deploy all
- start a shell in one of the running pods
- issue the "printenv" command

In our case, we can see all the environment variables, including the ones coming from the other deployments. The expected behaviour would be to see only those defined in the related deployment. In the case of env vars names identically in different deployments, they seem to have the right value, as if some precedence rule existed.

We have obviously done something wrong somewhere, but we can't find what, even after having studied the documentation and browsed the net to no avail.

Any suggestion will be more than welcomed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your problem still unresolved?

Comment: Not yet. To be honest we have not invested time for investigating it, but it would be nice to find an explanation about how this is supposed to work and if there is something wrong with our setup.

Comment: Could you paste your example yaml files? Which version of Kubernetes did you use?

Comment: I've done some tests recently to investigate the problem reported above, but it happens that I can't reproduce it. printenv now lists only env vars defined in the deployment. 
Since a lot of things have changed since them, maybe we did something wrong at that time and fixed it afterwards without being aware of.
Sorry for the posting about a non-existing problem.